# Designer Collection Editor, how to know current index?

Tags: c#, custom-controls

My control has a child control collection of `TabPage` type. I want to create a new child instance assigning a name according to its index. To do this, I need to know the current state of the collection. But how? `CreateInstance` only gives the item type, not the collection reference.

```
public class MyEditor : CollectionEditor
{
    public MyEditor(Type type) : base(type)
    {
    }

    protected override Type[] CreateNewItemTypes()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            typeof(TabPage)
        };
    }

    protected override object CreateInstance(Type itemType)
    {
        return new TabPage("Page 1"); //<-- How to know current index?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the lack of examples, I resorted to decompiling the .NET Framework and seeing how Microsoft did it. Microsoft's TabPageCollectionEditor was inside "System.Design.dll".

You can access the control which has the collection like this:

```
var control = Context?.Instance as MyTabControl;
```

Then it was a trivial thing to get current index:

```
int currentIndex = control.TabPages.Count;
```